# Не могу создать файл File.createTempFile

Tags: android

Все делал по уроку гугл но не работает. Даже ctrl+с ctrl+v делал.

```
private File createImageFile() {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "Selfie_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        File image = null;
        try {
            image = File.createTempFile(
                    imageFileName,       /*prefix*/
                    ".jpg",             /*suffix*/
                    storageDir          /*directory*/
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW Intents
        test = storageDir.toString() + imageFileName ;
        if(image == null)
            mCurrentPhotoPath = "null";
        else
            mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

mCurrentPhotoPath = null

tets = /storage/sdcard0/PicturesSelfie_20151130_173814_

как так?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.android.selfie" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Camera"
            android:label="@string/camera">
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Манифест в вопрос дабавьте.

Comment: Добавил. Я из MainActivity вызываю активность Camera а там уже вызываю `Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`

Comment: См. мой ответ. Возможно, также, понадобиться перенести `<uses-feature` из тега активити в корневой тег манифеста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего дело в отсутствии необходимых разрешений в манифесте в его основном теге. Попробуйте добавить их так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.android.selfie" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
    ....
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, вы правы. Я указал пермишн в разделе активити, а надо сразу в корне манифеста. А сколько времени и нервов. Сенкс.

Comment: @BogdanShulga, в начале все ошибаются, главное не сдаваться)